# AngularJS dependable dropdowns from json tree bind issue

Tags: angularjs, json, dropdown

building an app that retreives data from a database.
Created 2 dependable dropdowns 
1.Categories 
2. branches

all select options are coming from a json tree (Array in an Array) that is fetched by a service(Categories).

in controller i fetch json with :

```
$scope.categories = Categories.query();
```

in html i try below code:

```
<select class="form-control" name="category" ng-model="params.category" ng-options="item as item.name for item in categories track by item.category">
                        </select>

 <select class="form-control" name="branch" ng-model="params.branch" ng-options="branch as branch.name for branch in categories[params.category].branches track by item.category.branch">
                        </select>
```

Dropdown 1. Categories fetched ok  but Dropdown 2. branches doesnt work.

Can you guide??

Comment: in your ng-options for dropdown two, i think you cant use dot notation inside of the bracket notation, maybe just categories.params.category.branches. Although it be great to see a plunker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have an array of arrays, I think the `params.category` variable will hold a reference to an array, so you can't use it in the second select with `categories[params.category]` because you need to use the index and not the reference. I suggest you try: `categories[categories.indexOf(params.category)]`.

**EDIT:**
Since I don't know what your `categories` array looks like, and what a `branch` array looks like, I can only guess according to your code. **IF** your data structure is similar to what I think - [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/JxtJoTFpCRjd8payzaaU?p=info) is a working plunker.

The main idea is that if an element inside your `categories` array is an object and has a `branches` property, then after you put a reference to it in `$scope.params.category` than you can just access the `branches` property using dot notation (no need to go back to the `categories` array).

Comment: tried this :   categories[categories.indexOf(params.category)].branches    and now dropddown branches  just fetches-shows  all relative branches but cannot select any of them ?

Comment: Please see my edited answer. If this is not helpful enough - it will be easier to use the plunker for future discussion.

Comment: Very helpfull answer. also this worked in 2nd dropdown:  `code`  ng-options="branch as branch.name for branch in categories[categories.indexOf(params.category)].branches "> `code`  i have some other issues and i ll get back.Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good luck! It is [recommended](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to mark a helpful answer as 'accepted'.